# What does VueJS mean by calling themselves progressive framework?

Tags: vue.js

What is progressive framework that is meant by official documentation of VueJs?
What are the differences of progressive framework and monolithic framework? with breafe intro
May I have some example of any website for references what is progressive framework about?
I can't really understand.

Comment: They just mean you can use parts of the whole framework and progressively add more parts of it e.g. for example you could start with just using the view functionality and then add the router and later add vuex or just use it on a single page with a cdn or script tag and later move to using single file components.

Answer (score 23):

The corrected answer for "what does progressive mean" is given in their Vue intro video: "If you have an existing server side application, you can plug VUE into just one part of your application". You can then scale if you wish with their CORE libraries.

So, it's not "all or none".

Answer (score 1):

"Progressive" means its implemented as additional markup to html.if the model is updated the browsers HTML is updated, that is it reacts to model updates.

Vue.js not a monolithic framework

a monolithic application describes a single-tiered software application in which the user interface and data access code are combined into a single program from a single platform. A monolithic application is self-contained and independent from other computing applications.

Answer (score -4):

the word **"progressive"** means its implemented as additional markup to html. it basically a template model bound to a data model. if the model is updated the browsers html is updated, that is it reacts to model updates. Vue js in an example of progressive framework.

for example in vue. I have a template of html here like

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p>{{framework}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

here's my data or model

```
data() {
  return {
     framework: 'Vue js'
 }
}
```

so whenever I changed the value of framework variable into 'Angular'. The p tag text also will change into 'Angular'. In short, if the data model is updated the browsers html is also updated.

So **monolithic web framework**  is lightly faster to get started with, but less control over its workings, more chance of the framework not supporting your usecase, and higher long-term maintenance cost due to the inevitable need for workarounds. Example for a monolithic web framework [sail.js](https://sailsjs.com/get-started)

for more explanation please refer to this article [source](https://gist.github.com/joepie91/7f03a733a3a72d2396d6)

Comment: You are explaining reactivity.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the progressiveness of frameworks